# Unable to fetch Artifacts files after Teamcity builds

Tags: java, maven, teamcity, filenotfoundexception, mailx

I have a Java-Maven script that sends the mail of an artifact file from last successful build on Teamcity. But every time the build completes and the scripts run, below **File not found** error occur. Can anyone please help on this.

**Error:**
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /repository/download/94ecc0rt7op01pew/.lastSuccessful/target/project-report/project-report.html **(No such file or directory)**

**Code Snippet**

```
private static final String SMTP_SERVER = "projectServer.net";
private static final String USERNAME = "user1";
private static final String PASSWORD = "user1";

private static final String EMAIL_FROM = "user1@.com";
private static final String EMAIL_TO = "user1@.com";
private static final String EMAIL_TO_CC = "user1@.com";

private static final String EMAIL_SUBJECT = "Services Status Report as of ";
private static final String EMAIL_TEXT = "Please find the attached status report.";

public static void sendReport() {

    Properties prop = System.getProperties();
    prop.put("mail.smtp.auth", "false");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(prop, null);
    Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);

    try {
        
        String today =  new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format( new Date(new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy").parse(new Date().toString()).getTime()));
        msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(EMAIL_FROM));

        msg.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(EMAIL_TO, false));

        msg.setSubject(EMAIL_SUBJECT+today);

        // text-body
        MimeBodyPart p1 = new MimeBodyPart();
        p1.setText(EMAIL_TEXT);

        String cwd = new File("target").getAbsolutePath();
        
        System.out.println("PWD: "+cwd);
        String BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID = cwd.split("/")[5]; /* To get the build id */
        
        // file-attachment
        MimeBodyPart p2 = new MimeBodyPart();            
        FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource("/repository/download/"+BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID+"/.lastSuccessful/target/project-report/project-report.html");
        p2.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(fds));
        p2.setFileName(fds.getName());

        Multipart mp = new MimeMultipart();
        mp.addBodyPart(p1);
        mp.addBodyPart(p2);

        msg.setContent(mp);


        SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport) session.getTransport("smtp");

        // connect
        t.connect(SMTP_SERVER, USERNAME, PASSWORD);

        // send
        t.sendMessage(msg, msg.getAllRecipients());

        System.out.println("Response: " + t.getLastServerResponse());

        t.close();

    

}
```

Comment: Can you provide more context? Maybe a segment of the script? How is the project-report.html file generated?

Comment: Thanks Jeff. Please find the code snippet below, I have added the code snippet. Please check.

Comment: So the script is failing on this line: `FileDataSource fds = new FileDataSource("/repository/download/"+BUILD_TYPE_EXT_ID+"/.lastSuccessful/target/project-report/project-report.html");` I think you will need to investigate the last successful build. It doesn't look like the project-report.html file is being generated like it is supposed to. Sorry, it's hard to give an answer on this since I am not able to see your previous builds or any build steps. This one will take a bit of debugging.